# Calculating a min y axis value in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

If I create column chart that has values that are > 0 but much closer in value to each other than they are to 0 then the chart generated will have columns that look almost identical. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quHRk/1/).

However if I change the chart type to a line then the resulting chart is much nicer because the min yAxis value is calculated to a non-zero value so that the distribution of the values on the chart is much more obvious.

I could manually set a min yAxis value but I need this to work for any set of data and so it needs to be calculated. How could I achieve the same thing for a column chart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found where Highcharts calculates the min value for line charts (at least for linear axes). It's in the getTickPositions() function. Specifically these lines of code:

```
// pad the values to get clear of the chart's edges
if (!categories && !usePercentage && !isLinked && defined(min) && defined(max)) {
    length = (max - min) || 1;
    if (!defined(options.min) && !defined(userMin) && minPadding && (dataMin < 0 || !ignoreMinPadding)) {
        min -= length * minPadding;
    }
    if (!defined(options.max) && !defined(userMax)  && maxPadding && (dataMax > 0 || !ignoreMaxPadding)) {
        max += length * maxPadding;
    }
}
```

So it calculates the min as

```
length = ([max data value] - [min data value]) || 1
min = [min data value] - length * minPadding
```

The default for minPadding on the yAxis is 0.05 so

```
394.5 = 395 - ((405 - 395) * 0.05)
```

394.5 is rounded when creating the tick positions so the end result is 390.

What I've come up with so far is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chrish/aARTH/1/). (The minPadding default on the yAxis doesn't seem to be exposed so I've hardcoded it)

```
var data = [400,405,395];

Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};
Array.min = function( array ){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};

var min = Array.min(data);
var max = Array.max(data);

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: min - ((max-min) * 0.05)
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the yAxis value, for example:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
    },

    yAxis: {
       min: 390,
       startOnTick: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [400,405,395]
    }]
});
```

You can also set it to some kind of dynamic value in javascript (AVG(400, 405, 395) - 10%, for instance) that should give it enough scale.

Updated JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/quHRk/2/).
    ​