# highcharts get all of the minimum points of the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have almost 10 series in my chart.

1) How can I find the minimum point of all the series?

2) How can I set it as my chart's starting point like the red line?

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QruJv/):

```
xAxis: {                
    gridLineWidth:'1',
    gridLineDashStyle:'shortDot',
    tickInterval:1
},
yAxis: {                
    gridLineDashStyle:'shortDot',                              
},
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    crosshairs:[{
        width:1,
        color: 'black'
    }]
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        pointStart:1,
    }                
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222613/calculating-a-min-y-axis-value-in-highcharts.

Comment: So series should start by line or point?

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to wergeld.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use loop on each series / and point and return correct value.